# Lennox 96% Furnace Pressure Switch Fault and Schematic Diagram

Tags: furnace, lennox

Furnace: Lennox EL296UH090XV48C - 06
Installed: August 2015

We see E227, E229 and E271 for sometime. Overall, the codes mean that low pressure switch failed to close (hence inducer stopped and furnace stopped. This goes on for sometime and heat stage 2 is activated and keeps failing) At that time, furnace goes into soft lockdown. Error code list attached.

At this time, (Nest learning) thermostat keeps showing as if furnace is heating but it's heating/blower not running.

What turns it back on?

1. Turning power off/on to the furnace keeps it running again.
2. Automatic after some time - 2-5 hours.

How often does it occur?

1. Can't say for sure. It's totally random.
2. Seems like happens more frequently during colder days.

What I did so far?

1. Confirmed no blockage in exhaust flue pipe return - two black tubes coming from top-left in the picture titled furnace.
2. No blockage in drain to condensate pump.
3. Cleaned condensate pump and confirmed it's draining clearly.
4. Outside the house, exhaust and intake pipes do not have blockage.
5. Tried to 'help' furnace by adding couple of electric heaters to length the time period between the heating cycles. It increased timed but didn't quite help so indirectly confirmed there's no issue with the vent/drain inside the furnace.
6. Looked at the schematic for the furnace, particularly around low/high pressure switch. Question here - see below.

Questions/Issue.

1. Not sure what is causing this error codes to popup. So, need some help there.
2. Question about 6 above - when looking at the schematics, I noticed that probably electrical connections are not correct for the low pressure switch. Could someone confirm or let me know what did I miss? See attached pictures.

Thank you very much for your time.

[image: Schematic]
[image: Low Pressure Switch]
[image: Misleading Status On Thermostate]
[image: High Pressure Switch]
[image: Furance]
[image: Error Codes]